# Find the difference between two dates in Java

Tags: java

In Java, is there a way to find the number of days between two dates given that one or both of the dates could be before 1970 (i.e. Date object cannot be used)?

Comment: If it's before 1970, how is it represented then? Give detail.

Comment: Add some value (multiple of 4 years, for leap year) to the year to bring it up a "recent" date, then subtract the dates and add in the net effect of your fudging.  This should work for any year after 1900.  Before 1900 you have to account for 1900 **not** being a leap year.

Comment: `(to.getTime() - from.getTime()) / (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try GregorianCalendar.
Note that months are 0 based while days are 1 based

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

//january, 1st, 2012
GregorianCalendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 0, 1);
//march, 3rd, 1912
GregorianCalendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar(1912, 2, 3);
long differenceInSeconds = (c1.getTimeInMillis() - c2.getTimeInMillis()) / 1000;
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the Calendar class doesn't take into account things like leap years (and while a little irrelevant for this post) and day light savings. This will work if your trying to calculate the difference between dates within the same year, but errors will start creeping the wider the gap gets

Answer (score 6):

I would highly recommend [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net) library. Example:

```
Days.daysBetween(startDate.toDateMidnight() , endDate.toDateMidnight() ).getDays()
```

Answer (score 4):

Huh?  [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) can be used to represent earlier dates than 1970.  Just pass a negative number to its constructor.

```
System.out.println(new Date(-1000));
System.out.println(new Date("Jul 4 1776"));  // note: deprecated API.  Just an easy example
```

prints

```
Wed Dec 31 15:59:59 PST 1969
Thu Jul 04 00:00:00 PST 1776
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful to calculate days on base of timestamps like that:

> (to.getTime() - from.getTime()) / (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24)

no matter using Date or GregorianCalender.

This doesn't work in Europe, if the last Sunday on March is in this interval.

In Europe time is switched two times a year for one hour. 
 - Winter time ==> Summer time (last Sunday in March)
 - Summer time ==> Winter time (last Sunday in October)

**So the last Sunday in March has only 23 hours. In consequnce calculation returns one day less.**